# Math.min.apply() not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Math.min.apply is not working when have the 1L data in safari browser. Please find the below example,

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/38588/

```
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
function change(){
   var arr = [];
   for (var i=0; i<=100000; i++){
      arr.push(i);
   }
   document.getElementById('myTextField').value = Math.min.apply(null, arr);

}
```

When run that example except chrome it's working fine but in safari it throws the 
`Maximum call stack size exceeded` issue in console. how to avoid this?

Comment: Post the code here please. Your question shouldn't depend on others having to visit some other site.

Comment: If you have an exceptionally long Array, then this will happen because the stack size limit varies between browsers. You can do smaller chunks of the Array in a loop, always adding in the previous result.

Comment: @squint this is the code https://jsfiddle.net/blazeeboy/fNPvf/.. Ya i can able to acheive this using iterate the value.. but that's not gud right? because of it reduce the performance.

Comment: Please post the code directly in the question, not just a link, so that your question doesn't depend on others having to visit some other site. And you don't need to have a separate call to `Math.min` for every item. Do it in chunks. Maybe do 500 items in the array at a time by using `.apply()`.